# Get latest messages from kafka-node

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

i am using kafka-node consumer group with the following options

````
    ```const options = {
            kafkaHost: process.env.KAFKA_HOST,
            autoCommit: false,
            protocol: ['roundrobin'],
            fromOffset: 'latest',
            outOfRangeOffset: 'latest'
        }
    const consumerGroup = new ConsumerGroup(options as any, topic_all)```
````

But it still does not get the latest messages, how can i fetch only latest messages from consumer?

Comment: Which library is this? It'll be easier to help if you provide a little more context of the code

Comment: library is `kafka-node`

Comment: I’m reading your question as that you are only interested in the single, latest message. Is there reason for using a consumer group, rather than just a “consumer”, while not interested in using the consumer offset feature?